# Yii2 Summernote widget not working

Tags: yii2, summernote

Hello Friends I installed summernote widget through composer. It works fine but some of the options are not working. I mention it in the following image:

[image]

Please help me if you have any idea how to enable it thanks

This is my code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'remarks')->widget(Summernote::className(), [
    'clientOptions' => [
    ]
])->label(false); ?>
```

Comment: Which composer package is this?

Comment: marqu3s/yii2-summernote: composer code is : composer require marqu3s/yii2-summernote